# Induction - reducing the formula using algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, induction

I am having trouble to prove this reduction problem since I am stuck at showing how to reduce the function further using algebra. Any help would be appriciated.

> Show: $$f(n) = (n*2^n)+7$$

Induction holds true so

hypothesis: $f(n-1) = ((n-1)*(2^{n-1}))+7$

Solving:

\begin{align}f(n) &= (2^n)-7+2*f(n-1)\\
 &= (2^n)-7+2*(((n-1)*2^{n-1})+7)\\
 & = (2^n)+7+(((n-1)*4^{n-1}))
\end{align}

After this, i am stuck trying to reduce it even further. If anyone could help me out, that would be great. What algebra method should I be using to reduce it farter to show that $f(n) = (n*2^n)+7$

Answer (score 1):

> \begin{align}f(n) &= (2^n)-7+2*f(n-1)\\
>  &= (2^n)-7+2*(((n-1)*2^{n-1})+7)\\
>  & = (2^n)+7+(((n-1)*4^{n-1}))
> \end{align}

You made a mistake going from the second to last line to the last line. In particular:

$$2*2^{n-1} \not = 4^{n-1}$$

Rather:

$$2*2^{n-1} = 2^n$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}f(n) &= (2^n)-7+2*f(n-1)\\
 &= (2^n)-7+2*(((n-1)*2^{n-1})+7)\\
 & = (2^n)+7+(n-1)*2^{n}\\
 & = n*2^n+7\\
\end{align}

Comment: Ah, I see what you did there with the exponenet n-1. Thanks alot :)